# get javascript object from script in html

Tags: html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio, node-fetch

This is what I have, html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var imp_accountInfo = {
          "id": "6yb32e53e03g4",
          "nickname": "jack"
    };</script>
```

I want to get this part:

```
    {
      "id": "6yb32e53e03g4",
      "nickname": "jack"
    }
```

I tried to use cheerio but I just get lost so much stuff I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple regex can do it for you (although you haven't marked your question with regex):

```
/{[^}]+}/g
```

It simply starts with a left curly brace, then matches everything not being a right curly brace and ending with the final right curly brace. It gets exactly what you want.

**`Edit`** according to comment:

```
/imp_accountInfo\s=\s({[^}]+})/
```

That will find the first curly braces close to '`imp_accountInfo`'.

**How to use**:

Use String.match in JavaScript and use the *index `'1'`* of the resulting array.

**Edit2**:

I have expanded the regex, so now you can extract the `quoted` values between the curly braces:

```
/imp_accountInfo\s=\s{[^"]*"([^"]*)"[^"]*"([^"]*)"[^"]*"([^"]*)"[^"]*"([^"]*)"[^}]*}/
```

Still use String.match and you will get the content in the array.

Comment: Is there a way to find it by this part "imp_accountInfo", because i have several curly braces in my html